# Authy OneTouch approval/denial error

Tags: twilio, authy

I am using Authy for 2-factor authentication in my website. My code sends a push notification and I receive it in the Authy app on my phone. But the problem is sometimes when I try to accept/deny the request I get an error saying

> There was an error processing the transaction.

And it is strange when I change the Authy ID and send the request to my friend's phone number. He gets the request and is able to accept/deny it in his phone. So is this related to some number of tries per phone number? I use a test Authy account and a premium one. I get the above error on both.

Comment: I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio and I don't think we can solve this from Stack Overflow. I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and tell them all of this along with your account SID and Authy app name, they will be able to look into this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've talked to the support and it is a problem with the app itself. They have added proper error reporting in this situation now. This happens when the user gets deleted from Authy once. The temporary fix to this issue is the re-installation of the app. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Alternatively, you can delete the data for the app (within the settings), which will then require you to register within the app once again.  (Using Android Oreo)